# Bruns-Herzog problem 3.1.25

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, gorenstein

This is problem 3.1.25 (page 97) in *Cohen-Macaulay Rings* by Bruns and Herzog. The direction I am interested in is the following.

> Let $R$ be a Gorenstein local ring and $M$ a finite $R$-module. If the injective dimension of $M$ is finite, then prove that the projective dimension of $M$ is finite.

I am interested in knowing how to do this exercise by using results proved upto this point in the book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use induction on $d=\dim R$.

If $d=0$, then $\text{inj}\dim M=0$, so $M$ is injective. Take a short exact sequence $$0\longrightarrow N\longrightarrow F\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow 0$$ with $F$ free of finite rank, notice that $F$ is injective and then $\text{inj}\dim N<\infty$. Furthermore, $\text{inj}\dim N=0$ and then the short exact sequence is split. It follows that $M$ is projective.

If $d>0$, then choose $x\in m$ ($m$ is the maximal ideal of $R$) which is nonzerodivisor on $R$ and on $N$, where $N$ (in this case) is the $d$th syzygy of $M$. (One can do this, since from B&H, exercise 2.1.26, one knows that $N$ is $0$ or maximal CM, so $m$ cannot be contained in the set of zerodivisors of $N$, otherwise $\text{depth } N=0$ which implies $d=0$, contradiction.) Notice again that $\text{inj}\dim N<\infty$ and now specialize all by $x$ and apply the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Can you indicate how one could do exercise 2.1.26?

Comment: I just saw this comment from you, so i will post this exercise as a different problem. The above answer from you is very good, and i would like to vote it up but i dont know how to do that.