# Residue fields of Gorenstein local rings have finite injective dimension?

Tags: commutative-algebra

> If $(R,\mathfrak m,k)$ is a Gorenstein local ring, then show that $\textrm{inj dim}_R\ k$ is finite.

This was previously asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110488/finite-injective-dimension-of-the-residue-field-implies-that-the-ring-is-regular) as a second part of the question and remained unaswered, but I think it is independent of the first part and deserves a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this question is false, as can be seen using [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148407/bruns-herzog-problem-3-1-25/148664#148664). There it is shown that a finite generated $R$-module over a Gorenstein ring has finite projective dimension iff it has finite injective dimension. In the question above, if the injective dimension of $k$ is finite, then its projective dimension is finite, that is, $R$ is regular. But there are Gorenstein local rings which are not regular.